# Which Stack Exchange is proper for asking Microsoft Word related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question about Microsoft Word. It is the software itself based not coding related. The question is about table shapes. Which one is most proper ?

Answer (score 48):

If it's about using Microsoft Word, you should head over to [Super User](https://superuser.com/). They have quite a few [Word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) questions there already.

Comment: Super User is across the board in terms of OSes, Windows and Linux included, for power users. It's not for server or programming related stuff, and you'd have to think about Ask Different (Apple) and Ask Ubuntu (Ubuntu) for those specific platforms.

Comment: @mog: You're thinking of [Unix.SE]. More evidence there are too many overlapping sites.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: I beg to differ, given that those sites flourish. I think the argument is the same as with Linux "People have too much choice"...people who do not want to have choice and do not want to read the FAQ should not be allowed to vote in democratic elections, too. But to get back on the constructive road, the audiences are different. Super User has mostly all-rounders, while Unix & Linux has pretty good experts in that field. Well as it goes for Ask Ubuntu...I can't defend that...except to keep a certain crowd of users away from the other two sites.