# Is there a community for questions about MS Excel or Word?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a community for questions about Microsoft Excel or Word?

I have a question about conversion of Excel to Word and I don't know if there is a place on Stack Exchange.

Where I can ask it?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22922 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129110 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90919  and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246444 and ...

Answer (score 2):

You can ask in [Super User](https://superuser.com/), with the [Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) or [Word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) tags.

Before post your question read their [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) page.

---

<sup>About programming and software development is off-topic in Super User.</sup>